# Error in accessing skb (skb->data)

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, openwrt

I'm trying to allocate a sk_buff in my code and then access its skb->data area.
I get a NULL pointer deference.

OpenWRT: Barrier Breaker

Code:

```
struct sk_buff *skb = NULL;
skb = __dev_alloc_skb(2400,GFP_ATOMIC);
if (skb) {
    printk("head= %p \n data= %p \n tail= %p\n end= %p\n len= %d\n", skb->head,skb->data,skb->tail,skb->end,skb->len);
    memset(skb->data,0,2400);
    }
```

Dump:

I get the following stack trace:

```
[   61.200000] head = ce1dca00
[   61.200000] data = 00000b20
[   61.210000] tail = ce1dd360
[   61.210000] end = ce1dc9c0
[   61.210000] len = 0
[   61.210000] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000b20
[   61.220000] pgd = ce240000
[   61.220000] [00000b20] *pgd=2e554831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
[   61.230000] Internal error: Oops: 817 [#1] SMP ARM
[   61.230000] Modules linked in: eng qcserial pppoe ppp_async option iptable_nat usb_wwan sierra_net sierra qmi_wwan pppox ppp_generic pl2303 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ipv4 mac80211 ipt_MASQUERADE ftdi_sio ebtable_nat ebtable_filter ebtable_broute cfg80211 cdc_ether ath3k asix xt_time xt_tcpudp xt_tcpmss xt_string xt_statistic xt_state xt_recent xt_nat xt_multiport xt_mark xt_mac xt_limit xt_length xt_id xt_hl xt_helper xt_ecn xt_dscp xt_conntrack xt_connmark xt_connlimit xt_connbytes xt_comment xt_TCPMSS xt_REDIRECT xt_NETMAP xt_LOG xt_HL xt_DSCP xt_CT xt_CLASSIFY usbserial usbnet usbhid ums_usbat ums_sddr55 ums_sddr09 ums_karma ums_jumpshot ums_isd200 ums_freecom ums_datafab ums_cypress ums_alauda ts_kmp ts_fsm ts_bm slhc rfcomm nf_nat_irc nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack_irc nf_conntrack_ftp iptable_raw iptable_mangle iptable_filter ipt_REJECT ipt_ECN ip_tables hso hidp hid_generic hci_uart gsc_input ebtables ebt_vlan ebt_stp ebt_snat ebt_redirect ebt_pkttype ebt_mark_m ebt_mark ebt_limit ebt_ip6 ebt_ip ebt_dnat ebt_arpreply ebt_arp ebt_among ebt_802_3 e1000e crc_ccitt compat cdc_wdm cdc_acm btusb bnep bluetooth act_connmark act_skbedit act_mirred em_u32 cls_u32 cls_tcindex cls_flow cls_route cls_fw sch_hfsc sch_ingress configs hid evdev ledtrig_usbdev xt_LED ledtrig_netdev ledtrig_morse ledtrig_heartbeat ledtrig_gpio batman_adv libcrc32c ip6t_REJECT ip6table_raw ip6table_mangle ip6table_filter ip6_tables x_tables nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nfsd nfsv3 nfs bonding ip_gre gre e1000 ifb ip_tunnel tun snd_compress snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_timer snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device snd_hwdep snd soundcore vfat fat ntfs lockd sunrpc nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 regmap_spi regmap_i2c regmap_core lzo_decompress lzo_compress rfkill input_core ipv6 arc4 crypto_blkcipher usb_storage uhci_hcd gpio_button_hotplug ext4 crc16 jbd2 mbcache exportfs ptp crc32c crypto_hash [last unloaded: iwlwifi]
[   61.230000] CPU: 0 PID: 1850 Comm: hostapd Not tainted 3.10.49 #1
[   61.230000] task: cf97ac60 ti: ce1d6000 task.ti: ce1d6000
[   61.230000] PC is at __memzero+0x24/0x80
[   61.230000] LR is at 0x0
[   61.230000] pc : [<c000c1a4>]    lr : [<00000000>]    psr: 20000013
[   61.230000] sp : ce1d7d04  ip : 00000000  fp : ce1d7d2c
[   61.230000] r10: 00008914  r9 : 00000001  r8 : ce44d400
[   61.230000] r7 : 00004000  r6 : ce44d400  r5 : 00000008  r4 : ce094560
[   61.230000] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 000008e0  r0 : 00000b20
[   61.230000] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[   61.230000] Control: 00c5787d  Table: 2e24000a  DAC: 00000015
```

I have tried using alloc_skb, dev_alloc_skb also.

ath5k uses __dev_alloc_skb() and successfully uses the returned skb->data on the target platform.

Also the value of skb->data (data = 00000b20) seems to be relative. Is it relative to the skb->head.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use private methods (starting with `__`), use `alloc_skb` or `dev_alloc_skb` (for device drivers, it will be freed automatically) instead.

Also, it is always better to use the provided API for the instance of the `sk_buff` structure rather than accessing the private fields. See the existing usages for examples: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=dev_alloc_skb

Comment: Thanks for the info Vasily. I just created a fresh build of barrier breaker, and everything started working fine with dev_alloc_skb.                                                                                                                      I still could not digest the values of head, tail, end and data pointers: head = ce1dca00, data = 00000b20, tail = ce1dd360, end = ce1dc9c0                               , although the code is working fine.